# Want to replace "^^^" with "~" say abc^^^xyz should be replaced like abc~xyz

Tags: java, string

```
public class StringExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x = "^^^";
        String y = "~";
        String s = "abc^^^xyz";
        if (s != null && s.indexOf(x) > -1)
            s = s.replaceAll(x,y);
        System.out.println("s :" + s);
    }
}
```

It is not giving proper result.

- Input

  > abc^^^xyz
- Actual Output

  > ~a~b~c~^~^~^~x~y~z
- Expected Output

  > abc~xyz

Comment: replaceAll() takes a REGEX as argument.. you need to escape the `^`s

Comment: what I don't understand is, why you did `"aaa^^^bbb".replaceAll("^^^","~")` you got `~a~b~c~^~^~^~x~y~z` instead of `~aaa^^^bbb` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. The latter takes a regex expression, in which `^` is a reserved character.

Comment: I blame Sun for misleading method naming.

Comment: @KarolS `replace` was added in a later version of Java. By then it was too late to rename `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

use `replace()` in place of `replaceAll()`

```
s = s.replace(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
String str = "abc^^^xyz";
String replaceAll = str.replaceAll("\\^+", "~");
```

> **Note :** all you need is to escape char (**^**)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the ^ characters.

```
public class StringExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "\\^\\^\\^";
        String y = "~";
        String s = "abc^^^xyz";
        if (s != null && s.indexOf(x) > -1)
            s = s.replaceAll(x,y);
        System.out.println("s :" + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either

```
s= s.replaceAll("\\^{3}","~");
```

or

```
s=s.replace("^^^","~");
```

in fact, the `replace()` method calls `replaceAll()` internally.

and you can save the `s.indexOf(x) > -1` check.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should be using `replace(x,y)` rather than `replaceAll(x,y)` in this instance, you can still use `replaceAll()`, just quote the first argument.

This will convert the regular expression into a literal string.

```
Pattern.quote(x)
```

[`quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) will escape reserved; regular expression characters like so:

```
\Q^^^\E
```

Example for completeness:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "^^^";
        String y = "~";
        String s = "abc^^^xyz";

        if (s != null && s.indexOf(x) > -1) {
            s = s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(x), y);
        }
        System.out.println("s :" + s);
    }
}
```